# Need solution for error after continuously loading a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried making a website that updates or loads a part of it after a few seconds. After I load in the website and a few seconds to minutes later (depends on how long I input the time in the code) of constantly loading a part of the site, it would return:

> Aw, Snap! 
>  Something went wrong while displaying this webpage.

This is the script I use in constantly loading the page:

```
setInterval(function(){
            refresh() // this will run after every 36 seconds
        }, 36000);

        function refresh() {
            $('#myChart').load(location.href + "#myChart>*","");
        }
```

Honestly, I don't know how the code inside the `function refresh()` works.
If you would please help me in understanding both things, it would be of great help.

Comment: It sounds like you're causing a stack overflow, as for your refresh, the second argument to `.load()` is a callback function, which is optional, so don't pass `""` into it.

Comment: How do solve that stack overflow?

Comment: Don't load the same page you're on into the page you're on. The recursion causes the `setInterval` to double each time.

Answer (score -1):

You're causing a stack overflow because the url of your `.load()` is the same as the page you're on. So it loads the same page into the "myChart" element, which then starts another `setInterval`. So now you have 2 `setInterval` running, then when it loads again, you have 4 running, and then 8, and so on.

I'm not sure the purpose of loading the page you're currently on into the page you're currently on. Perhaps you mean to load a different url? If you do that, then you won't have a stack overflow.

## Demo

https://repl.it/@AnonymousSB/SO53360989

```
setInterval(function(){
  refresh() // this will run after every 36 seconds
}, 36000);

function refresh() {
  $('#myChart').load(location.href + "/path/to/another/page.htm");
}
```

If you're just trying to auto-reload the page you're on, then try this.

```
function refresh() {
  window.location.reload(true);
}

setTimeout(refresh, 36000);
```

Comment: Is there a way to stop the stack overflow without the need to stop the loading of that part of the page? It's just that I need to constantly update the data in the page.

Comment: @AldrineNAX. I ran a test and discovered it's caused by loading the page you're on into the "myChart" element. Each time refresh gets called, setInterval gets doubled.

Comment: Yeah... reload is not the problem. Keeping both old and new pages. Nice solution @AnonymousSB

Comment: Only issue... page might flicker on full page reload. Better would be to give a different URL for just the chart without the script.

Comment: What do I need to do to stop it from doing that and just load a part of the html page? My goal is to load/reload a part of the html page to constantly update data